# Selenium GUI testing?

Tags: user-interface, testing, selenium

I am working on function testing using selenium.

But on GUI testing I need help.

How selenium RC can help to automate the GUI testing like position of object, color, alignments of object in web pages.

Please suggest if any selenium API is available  / or we need to use any plug in for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably able to do the thing you mentioned. Explore Selenium API doc.

1. Position of object:

   ```
     getElementHeight(), 
     getElementPositionLeft(), 
     getElementPositionTop(), 
     getElementWidth()
   ```
2. Element Color/alignment: You can retrieve the element's color specific attributes like `color`  or `style` and check for expected value. For that you can use `getAttribute()` method. Also `getElementIndex()` might be useful.

All you have do is try to explore selenium APIs.

Hope this helps.